# classic is not defined err when trying to start Extjs6 AdminDashboard app

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I get this error in browser console `Uncaught ReferenceError: classic is not defined` when I try to start up Admin Dashboard app with command `sencha app watch` or `sencha app watch classic` . 
Here is a screenshot: [image: screenshot].
Sencha cmd version is 6.0.2.14.

If I switch to sencha cmd 6.1.0.65 I cant even build app. After `sencha app build -dev` or `sencha app build classic` I get error in console:

```
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Timed out waiting for sass build completion
[ERR]     at sun.reflect.Delegati
[ERR] ngMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 2 minutes 25 seconds
[ERR] ================= Phantomjs Output =================
[ERR] loading page http://localhost:1841/sass/example/fashion.html?phantomjs=true
successfully loaded page http://localhost:1841/sass/example/fashion.html?phantomjs=true
loading phantomjs adapter
== Unhandled Error ==
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.uses.length')


  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:921 in getLoadIndexes
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:963 in expandUrl
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:999 in expandUrls
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:1024 in expandLoadOrder
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:1042 in getUrls
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:1060 in getEntries
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:1091 in loadEntries
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:696 in processRequest
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:716 in load
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:2163 in onCachedAssetsReady
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:2128 in load
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:2069
  http://localhost:1841/sass/example/bootstrap.js:822 in readyStateChange


[ERR] ============= End Phantomjs Output =================
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/projects/SenchaTestDemo/AdminDashboard/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:335: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/projects/SenchaTestDemo/AdminDashboard/.sencha/app/slice-impl.xml:386: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/projects/SenchaTestDemo/AdminDashboard/.sencha/app/slice-impl.xml:387: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/projects/SenchaTestDemo/AdminDashboard/.sencha/app/slice-impl.xml:122: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Timed out waiting for sass build completion
```

Do you have any ideas on what is going on?

Thanks.

P.S: Here is a [link](https://github.com/sencha/SenchaTestDemo) to Admin Dashboard app example.

Comment: did you try to narrow the issue? like removing the sass folder

Comment: @aviram83 I`ve found [working example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard) and with a source code from github it is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Cmd isssue:**
Use Cmd 6.0.2.14, there seems to be [an issue](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?308882-Sencha-Cmd-v6.1.0.65-Sass-Timeout) on 6.1.0.65 while compiling sass.

**Build issue:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: classic is not defined
```

So you  probably downloaded the the example, navigated to the folder and run `sencha app watch` right? In the example there is no framework in the ext/ folder and it seems that Cmd automatically downloaded the public version of the framework which is unfortunately old, you need 6.0.1.250.

So delete everything which is in `SenchaTestDemo-master\AdminDashboard\ext` and manually copy the latest Ext 6.0.1.250 framework to it, which you can download from sencha.com

Comment: By default there is [no /ext folder](https://github.com/sencha/SenchaTestDemo/tree/master/AdminDashboard) at all so you need to do `sencha app build` first. `sencha app upgrade 6.0.1.250` returns `Application structure already at current cmd version` so I dont think thats a case. Thank you for answer tho